# Implication of the open mapping Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I think this is a very simple problem, but to my shame I have been working at it for hours. In my class on functional analysis, we were presented the open mapping theorem. The theorem states that given $E$ and $F$, two Banach spaces, and $T \in L(E,F)$,  a sujective mapping, then

$\exists r> 0$ $such$ $that$ $B_r(0) \subset T(B_1(0))$. From this, it follows that the image of open sets are open.

The professor then claimed that it implies $\exists c > 0$ $for$ $which$ $\forall y \in F, \exists x \in E$ $such$ $that$ $T(x)=y$ and $\left\lVert x \right\rVert$ $\leqslant$ $c\left\lVert y \right\rVert$.

I can't find the $c$ in question though I know it depends in some way on $r$. Could someone help me?

Comment: ${ry\over 2\|y\|}\in B_r(0)\subseteq T(B_1(0))$

Comment: I can't see how this helps to make the inequality holds. It gives us some $x$ of norm less than 1 which corresponds to this scaled $y$ but how do we go on and find the $c$? Thank you!

Comment: If $T(x)= {ry\over 2 \|y\|},$ then $T(x_1) = y,$ where $x_1={2\|y\|x\over r}.$ Can you now estimate the norm of $x_1$ in terms of $\|y\|$?

Comment: Ok ok got it. Hahahaha! Thank you very much